# what does "./wallet balance" mean?

Tags: bash, hyperledger-fabric

I am a beginner with bash and I'm using an open source file which have this sentence `./wallet balance` at the end of the file , Could any body tell me what dose it mean ?! here's the code inside the opensource file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
C_RED="\033[31;01m"
C_GREEN="\033[32;01m"
C_YELLOW="\033[33;01m"
C_BLUE="\033[34;01m"
C_PINK="\033[35;01m"
C_CYAN="\033[36;01m"
C_NO="\033[0m"

################################################################################
### MAIN #######################################################################
################################################################################

if [[ ${#} -gt 0 ]]; then
    printf "${C_RED}balance does not require any argument.\n"
    printf "${C_YELLOW}usage: ${C_NO}%s\n" "balance"
    exit 1
fi
./wallet balance
```

Comment: `wallet` is a binary file/or script or any executable (run "`file ./wallet`" to see type) ,its prefixed with its path. the path is `./` it means current directory. `balance` is the argument passed to the binary. Hope it helps.

Comment: @PS., no particular reason to believe it's a binary; could be any other kind of executable as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ,agreed added instruction to check the type of the file. Its could be any executable.

Comment: thanks a lot this really helps ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it means run the command called "wallet" which is to be found in the current directory "./" and provide it with a single parameter "balance".

I use the term "command" above, but in linux it could be lots of thins, for example it could be an excutable script such as a shell script, a compiled program (e.g. C) an alias etc.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and therein the bullet point regarding questions which "...are not about programming as defined in the help center" (a definition which permits only questions *exclusive* to software development). The OP may have encountered this command in a script, but it's not in any way scripting-specific.